# How to find out the remote Address in node.js if it is HTTPS request?

Tags: https, node.js, ip

HI. in node.js, if it is http request, I can get the remoteAddress at req.connection.remoteAddress,

so, how to get it if https request?  I find there is req.socket.remoteAddress but I'm not sure.  Please advice. thanks.

Comment: Are you using a HTTP server or making a HTTP request?

Comment: take a look here: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.7/api/https.html

Comment: so, when the http request come in, I want to know the remote IP address.  It doesn't appear at the req.connection as normally would. I see there is req.socket.remoteAddress but not sure if it is the one I should use. :)

Comment: are you sure your making a proper HTTPS ajax request?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It appears something is strange/broken indeed.
As of node 0.4.7, it seems http has remoteAddress available on:

- req.connection.remoteAddress
- req.socket.remoteAddress

on https, both of these are undefined, but

- req.connection.socket.remoteAddress

does work.
That one isn't available on http though, so you need to check carefully.
I cannot imagine this behavior is intentional.

Comment: None of them are available on 0.6.x. How do we get the remote ip address from a request on `http.createServer`?

Comment: Skip that - `connection.remoteAddress` _is_ available, it's just not listed in the Eclipse debugger. No idea why.

Comment: I tried req.connection.socket.remoteAddress and yes, it is working on https which seems to be weird.

Answer (score 10):

Since googling "express js ip" directly points to here, this is somehow relevant.

[Express 3.0.0 alpha](https://github.com/visionmedia/express#installation) now offers a new way of retrieving IP adresses for client requests.
Simply use [`req.ip`](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/request.js#L337). If you're doing some proxy jiggery-pokery you might be interested in `app.set("trust proxy", true);` and [`req.ips`](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/request.js#L353).

I recommend you to read the whole discussion in the [Express Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/express-js/tqiKZKew0oI/kn27alYiO8wJ).

Answer (score 6):

```
var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || 
     req.connection.remoteAddress || 
     req.socket.remoteAddress ||
     req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;
```

Note that sometimes you can get more than one ip address in req.headers['x-forwarded-for'], specially when working with mobile phones accessing your server (wifi and carrier data).

Comment: other headers to consider: 'x-cluster-client-ip' (rackspace LB) and 'x-real-ip' (default nginx proxy/fcgi)

Answer (score 3):

As well `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']` is easily manipulated so you need a properly configured proxy server.

Is better to check `req.connection.remoteAddress` against a list of known proxy servers before to go with `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']`.

Comment: Very good observation. Do you think there's any way to determine from a Request if it is a proxy or an end client?