# What's difference between IncomingMessage's "socket", "connection" and "connection.socket"?

Tags: node.js, express

While checking "how to get remote address for express.js request" I have found that where are quit a [tricky way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999379/how-to-find-out-the-remote-address-in-node-js-if-it-is-https-request) to do so:

```
 req.connection.remoteAddress || 
     req.socket.remoteAddress ||
     req.connection.socket.remoteAddress
```

`node.js` documentation holds near no information about that `connection` property of `IncomingMessage` object, so I suspect that it's some legacy things. Is it any information available how `api` has changed over time and is the `req.socket.remoteAddress` a safe way to use in modern `express.js` installs?

Answer (score 1):

Try to stick to what is documented. [`message.socket`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_message_socket) is shown in the HTTP documentation, so try to use that.